# VS Code Ports Panel Appearance

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to change the highlight yellow color in the PORTS panel. Is this even possible?

[image]

Comment: the background colour? the foreground (text) colour? both?

Comment: Just the background. It is straining the eyes!

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the Theme used and json file setting: `tree.tableOddRowsBackground`.

Answer was pulled from [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/207857#issuecomment-2003542399)